# How to create a product finder/selector in my Magento store?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, selection

I want to create an interactive Product <del>selection survey or quiz</del> *selector* in my Magento store. The <del>quiz</del> *selector* will ask a number of questions with multiple answers, leading to a certain product depending how the customer answers each question.

You can see an example here of what I want to create:
http://www.nationwideplatforms.co.uk/platform-selector *(having a product selector that leads to advising the right forklift vehicle based on a number of questions)*

Would anybody be able to point me in the way of a plugin they think would achieve this or where to start, as I can't find much online at all.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot answer this in much detail as it is too broad. Here are a few general tips and pointers:

- Create a custom attribute set for your products with all attributes you want to have questions about.
- Identify the products that should be included in the product selector by: 1) category, 2) the created attribute set name, OR 3) a custom attribute `product_selector` which is `yes` or `no` whether or not to include it in the product selector
- Build the product selector using Javascript. Showing the first question and when going to the next, hide the current question and show the next one.
- At the end, get the right product selection by posting all the answers via Ajax, build a product collection with all the answers as conditions and return a product list.

Answer (score 0):

This extension will be helpful for you. 
https://marketplace.magento.com/encoresky-yearmakemodel.html

Comment: You can check the demo here http://mage.encoreskydev.com/year-make-model

Comment: you can try mageants [magento 2 product parts finder](https://www.mageants.com/product-parts-finder-extension-for-magento-2.html) extension before go to purchase test demo